# Outputting list of unique unicode characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I am parsing some text in Ruby that contains Unicode character that I would like to transcribe to ASCII values in one output file and HTML encoding in another.  Is there a simple way of spitting out the non-ASCII characters found in a file?  For example:

```
\u00A0 #should become a " " in the text text file, but &nbsp; in the html output file
```

I'm going to manually transcribe them based upon my needs and would like to output a list of unique characters I'll need to transcribe from my initial input file.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method that helps to extract the characters found in your string:

```
"foo\u00A0bar".chars.to_a
# => ["f", "o", "o", " ", "b", "a", "r"]
```

Since some of these characters may be multi-byte UNICODE characters you might want to expand that into bytes as well, to be more thorough:

```
"foo\u00A0bar".chars.to_a.collect { |c| [ c, c.bytes.to_a ] }
# => [["f", [102]], ["o", [111]], ["o", [111]], [" ", [194, 160]], ["b", [98]], ["a", [97]], ["r", [114]]]
```

The array breaks down the specific bytes used to construct that character. In this case the non-breaking space shows up as `" "` but is actually `[194, 160]` internally.